# kubernetes network performance issue: moving service from physical machine to kubernetes get half rps drop

Tags: kubernetes

I setup a kubernetes cluster with 2 powerful physical servers (32 cores + 64GB memory.) Everything runs very smooth except the bad network performance I observed.

As comparison: I run my service on such physical machine directly (one instance). Have a client machine in the same network subset calling the service. The rps can goes to 10k easily. While when I put the exact same service in kubernetes version 1.1.7, one pod (instance) of the service in launched and expose the service by ExternalIP in service yaml file. With the same client, the rps drops to 4k. Even after I switched to iptable mode of kube-proxy, it doesn't seem help a lot.

When I search around, I saw this document https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/02/05/measuring-docker-cpu-network-overhead/

Seems the docker port-forwarding is the network bottleneck. While other network mode of docker: like --net=host, bridge network, or containers sharing network don't have such performance drop. Wondering whether Kubernetes team already aware of such network performance drop? Since docker containers are launched and managed by Kubernetes. Is there anyway to tune the kubernetest to use other network mode of docker?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure Kubernetes networking in a number of different ways when configuring the cluster, and a few different ways on a per-pod basis. If you want to try verifying whether the docker networking arrangement is the problem, set `hostNetwork` to true in your pod specification and give it another try ([example here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/f7f60004eb92333849b75dbd8eeb75ba20afdf0e/examples/newrelic/newrelic-daemonset.yaml#L22)). This is the equivalent of the docker --net=host setting.

Comment: Hi, Alex, thanks for your quick answer. I tried out hostNetwork: true in my replication controller today. I removed ExternalIP flag I used and add hostNetwork: true to service.yaml. The throughput goes up just like running service on physical machine. That's great.

However, after second thought, using the hostNetwork means only one pod can run on this physical machine, others will fail for conflict port. I'd like to achieve the throughput as well as scalability. Any good way to it?

Comment: It'll only prevent you from running more than one pod that uses that particular port and needs host networking. Other pods can still share the machine with the one using host networking. If the other pods are very network-intensive as well, they may not be a good fit to be on the same machine anyways because they'll be fighting over the machine's NIC.

Comment: If you start a kubernetes pod, it will use docker's default bridge network. To get cross-host IPs you need to use an overlay (eg: flannel), this is in addition to the docker bridge. There is a known overhead from both the veth/bridge configuration used by docker, and from encapsulation/vxlan/whatever your SDN employs to route packets, that make container networking slower than sending packets out of raw sockets using "real" IPs (which is what happens with net=host). In 1.2 there will be support for CNI plugins which allows you to replace the default docker bridge with eg: ipvlan.

Comment: You don't NEED to run overlay, it's just easier for many settings.  You didn't say whether you are using overlay or not?  Unfortunately, there is some network overhead just from using veth and bridges.  We're working to find better answers for containers in general.

Comment: Alex, thanks for the explanation! The scalability i'm talking about is running multiple same pods on one physical machine. Which means they will face port confliction in this case. Seems the net=host is not the answer i'm looking for.

Comment: HI, Prashanth, From the docker network testing result here: https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/02/05/measuring-docker-cpu-network-overhead/  seems the docker bridge mode is not that bad from physical ips. Are you saying the overlay enlarge the overhead? And whatever we use to route the package, the network performance will drop like that? However, the overhead seems too much. In latest testing, my service reach 27,000 rps on one physical device while it drops to 7,000 rps in kubernetes if just one pod. Will ipvlan in kube 1.2 help a lot?

Comment: HI, Tim, seems flannel service is on by default after I deployed kubernetest cluster. Is there anyway to turn it on or off? As I mentioned in previous comment, the rps drops from 27,000 to 7,000. The overhead looks too much than it should be. Where is the major overhead comes from?

Comment: BTW, how do I tell which network mode is being used by kubernetes pods? like bridge, port forwarding, etc. I was using ExternalIP setting in service.yaml. Does that switch to port forwarding from bridge mode?

Comment: @Prashanth B, one thing to clarify. The rps drops is measured from a bare metal client outside of kubernetes cluster. Wondering when an outside client accessing kube pods which is exposed by ExternalIP, which network mode is being used? port forwarding? What is the detail of package flowing from a client out of kube cluster into the pods, the package is routed by a hide NAT, or something else?

Comment: Yeah sorry, you don't need an overlay if you're willing to wire up the networking yourself (i.e you need some routing protocol in place to handle subnetting). Since you're using flannel, make sure you're using the vxlan backend, udp encap is pretty slow. Also check that you're using the iptables proxier and if you're not, either set the  `net.experimental.kubernetes.io/proxy-mode=iptables` on node obj, or set --proxy-mode=iptables on kube-proxy directly (it's the default in 1.2).

Comment: I can confirm Alex's observation in my own docker performance testing http://glennengstrand.info/software/performance/mysql/postgres/docker I saw --net=host performance increase by 10% for throughput and lower latency by 30%.